# Efficient way to perform approximated search?

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-11g-r2

I have to perform a join between `table_a` and `table_b`, using three fields as key being one of them the date of the event, say, both tables have `id1`, `id2` and `evnt_time` for eache record.

As it happens though, the `evnt_time` can be displaced in a few seconds between these tables. Thus the join has to behave sort of `table_a.id1 = table_b.id1 and table_a.id2 = table_b.id2 and table_a.evnt_time ~ table_b.evnt_time`, where:

- `~` means approximately, given `+` or `-` seconds
- There must be a way to give `~` parameters of how precise should be. e.g.: `table_a.evnt_time ~(2) table_b.evnt_time` will join `table_a.evnt_time` with `table_b.evnt_time - 2s`, `table_b.evnt_time - 1s`, `table_b.evnt_time`, `table_b.evnt_time + 1s` and `table_b.evnt_time + 2s`.

To tackle the situation, there are a few possibilities I am experimenting, but my doubt is on which architecture should I use to perform a *very* efficient "approximated join" - these tables are partitioned, sub-partitioned and each sub part may contain *billions of records*... (although I have a reasonable amount of resources).

For once, I thought of storing the *unique sencond* of the event (i.e. second it happened since julian calendar) on both sides so the real join (give a "`~(2)`") could simply look like:

```
select *
from
    table_a,
    table_b
where
    table_a.id1 = table_b.id1
    and table_a.id2 = table_b.id2
    and (table_a.evnt_sec = table_b.evnt_sec 
        or table_a.evnt_sec = table_b.evnt_sec + 1
        or table_a.evnt_sec = table_b.evnt_sec + 2
        or table_a.evnt_sec = table_b.evnt_sec - 1
        or table_a.evnt_sec = table_b.evnt_sec - 2)
```

But I am unsure of how efficiently would that perform with the indexes and scans..

This is just an example, I am not stuck to any sort of architecture.
Also, I am using Oracle 11gR2.

Comment: What's the cardinality of the evnt_sec column? How many evnt_sec per (id1,id2)? What indexes are already in place? Is such an approximate match likely to cause multiple rows returned because of its approximateness (not that it's a word :P )? (IE: Is the data per id1,id2 close together, as defined by evnt_sec?)

Comment: I am working on a few test records at the moment so couldn't really tell, but as soon as I have a more real bulk of data, I'll make sure update this info.

Comment: On what columns are the tables partitioned?

Comment: Floor the date to the nearest 5 seconds (or what ever jitter you want) and performe regular join.

Comment: @haki: no, that will not work. If the event time is 00:0:05 and 00:00:06 a join will happen because both times are truncated to 00:00:05. If the times are 00:00:04 and 00:00:05 than the first is truncated to 00:00:00 and no join will happen. This does not make sense because for both pairs the difference in time is the same, just 1 second. So in both situations a join should happen.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need to use is a Nonequi join

```
select *
from
    table_a,
    table_b
where
    table_a.id1 = table_b.id1
    and table_a.id2 = table_b.id2
    and table_a.evnt_sec BETWEEN table_b.evnt_sec -2 and table_b.evnt_sec +2
```

Comment: what about using the ANSI INNER JOIN syntax instead?

Comment: @KookieMonster ANSI INNER JOIN syntax is not very  popular in the Oracle user community. Maybe because it is seldom used in examples in the Oracle manuals.